# How to add test cases for Link using jest /enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to write some test cases using jest and enzyme,I am unable to add test cases for Link and Please suggest if any more test cases needs to be added

these is styled component, and when should we spy /mock function

displayErr.tsx

```js
export const DisplayErr = React.memo<Props>(({ text, SearchLink }) => (
    <Section>
      <h1>{text}</h1>

      {!SearchLink && <Link to={getPath('SEARCH')}>some text</Link>}
    </Section>
));
```

displayErr.test.tsx

```js
describe('Error Msg', () => {
  it('styled component', () => {
    const output = mount(<DisplayErr text="hello world" SearchLink={true} />);
    const link = output.find(Link).find({ to: '/Search' });
    expect(output.find(Section).text()).toEqual('hello world');
    //expect(link).toBe('<div class="link">Login</div>');//error
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `Link` will render based on the `SearchLink` props. As you are passing it as true, it wont be available in the DOM. Pass `SearchLink=false` and execute the unit tests.

```
describe('Error Msg', () => {
       it('styled component', () => {
       const output = mount(<DisplayErr text="hello world" SearchLink=false/>)
      expect(output.find(Link).props().to).toEqual('/search');
    });
```

Let me know if you are facing the same issue.

Comment: "Invariant Violation: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>"

Comment: Try with `shallow` instead of `mount`

Comment: getting different error,
 expect(output.find(Section).text()).toEqual('hello world');
is failing
 Expected: "hello World"
    Received: "hello World<Link />"

Comment: Try this - expect(output.find('Section h1').text()).toEqual('hello world')

Comment: “text” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

Comment: Just for testing - expect(output.find('h1').text()).toEqual('hello world'); Is this working ?

Comment: expect(output.find('h1').text()).toEqual('hello world')--- this works